# I get "Source not found" when debugging my Java code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm trying to debug my Java application in Eclipse however when I hit a breakpoint I simply see the following instead of my source:

[image: Source not found message]

If I change the stack frame in the Debug window then I can see the function name change in the tab - this is definitely my code, the line number is correct and I'm using the latest build but I still can't get Eclipse to show the source (despite it being open in another tab!)

I'm new to Eclipse and so I'm struggling to find my way around, but everything that I've stumbled across so far seems fine to me.

What might cause this to happen and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sounds like the 'source lookup path' section if you edit the debug configuration isn't setup correctly?

Comment: I'm new to eclipse and so I don't necessarily know what I'm looking for but I've managed to find a screen named "Source Lookup Path" that appears to list at least all the folders I would expect it to.  Could you go into more detail on what I should be looking for?

Comment: Run > Debug configurations > Find it listed > Source > Add > Add your project. See if that helps.

Comment: That did the trick - what confused me was that if I drilled down under the "Default" entry those same projects were listed as child entries.  Is that not good enough?

Comment: The current version of Eclipse doesn't let you specify source from "Debug Configurations" any more. Now, you go to the Debug window, right click your project, and click "Edit Source Lookup".

Answer (score 15):

Click on "Edit Source Lookup Path" button and then click on Add button then Java Project and include your imported project .. Hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 10):

I also had this issue in MyEclipse Blue. I resolved it by following these steps:

1. Debug the project.
2. Right click on the Thread (Which you will see in Debug tab) and click on the "Edit Source lookup"
3. New window will open and hit the "Add" button and Select the "Java Project".
4. Get all the project that is listed over there.
5. Restart your server.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem with my eclipse maven project. I fought with this issue quite a long time then I tried to rebuild projet with

```
mvn clean eclipse:eclipse
```

and it helped.

Answer (score 3):

When I faced this problem for the very first time, I've already done all the steps mentioned here. Curiously, my problem happened when I've copied a project into another place. Anyway, the debug starts to work without warnings, after simply remove all breakpoints that was originated from the original project.
Sorry about my English , I'm not fluent.

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem and none of the suggestions above worked. What did work, was deleting the local workspace and from Eclipse checking out from the repository again. The problem occured for everybody previously working with Netbeans and making the switch to Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Select Project
- Right click
- debug
- Debug configuration
- Select Source Tab
- Click on add button
- Select Java Project
- Add your project there with check box

Comment: This is the correct answer in most cases. And remember to re-start the debug after doing everything from this list.

Answer (score 1):

For local projects I've solved it by selecting the "Resolve Workspace artifacts" checkbox in the Debug Configurations.

Comment: Where can I find "Debug Configurations"? is that a menu item somewhere? thanks

Comment: Click down arrow near "bug" icon. "Debug Configurations" is the second item from bottom on the list.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error while debug in eclipse. You can fix it through edit source look up. **But make sure once you attach the Project You need to stop the server and again start in Debug mode. It will work.**

Here is the detail steps :

> Click on "Edit Source Lookup Path" button .
>   Then click on Add button.
>   Select Java Project and include your imported project
>   **Then stop the server and start it in Debug mode** and hit your service. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

After trying most of the solutions here, try this too once -

Close all the .java files from the editor, in fact, close all **unrelated** projects in eclipse.
And try running the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding the class file into the src folder within the project. Hope this method may help.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was running my server using a maven tomcat plugin. When I deployed using my configured server in Eclipse (generating a war file and copying it into my tomcat directory), I didn't have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In your debug configuration add goals as "clean install"in the maven build con

Answer (score 0):

This is an expansion on JAB's answer:
Click "Edit Source Lookup..." > Add... > Workspace Folder > Project > select your folder > check ***Search subfolders*** box > OK.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:Window-->Go to preferences-->Java-->Click on JRE-->Edit--->Restore Default and click on Finish.

**Update your Project before Debugging the code!**

Alas! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This occurred to me when my working git branch is updated from code in master branch. I have already run **mvn clean install** after the pull, but seems I had to update projects after the maven build so that project source code and JAR build code gets synchronized.

Right click on your project -> Maven -> Update Project, then select all the
maven modules available and press OK. This resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. After banging my head for several hours, I finally noticed that although Maven was building the project successfully, the source file I was trying to step into had an incorrect package statement and that is why the 'Source Not Found' eclipse problem was happening. When I corrected the package statement and rebuilt the project, the debugger found source file and stopped on my breakpoint.