# If I debug JSF webapp it gives me SOURCE NOT FOUND

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jsf, glassfish

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I get “Source not found” when debugging my Java code in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754207/i-get-source-not-found-when-debugging-my-java-code-in-eclipse)

I`m using Eclipse Juno, Glassfish and I try to debug a JSF webapp.
I start the server in debug mode, I enter a page, I do an action to enter an action method.
The debug starts, the class name in the class tab is correct but with .method (ex. LoginForm.loginAction()), the icon near the name is the icon of the stack trace and in the content, where my sources should be, I get a Source not found...
but I can see the variables correctly, the line number in the stack trace, but no source...

I debuged JSF, but with previous versions of Eclipse. This is very strange...

Comment: Thank you. I was pretty sure it was a Eclipse issue, but I had to give the complete scenario.
I followed the link and it resolved my issue. 
Again thank you!
Maybe it is a bug in Eclipse Juno, because in other releases it worked out of the box.

Comment: I don't know if reinstalling the Eclipse IDE would help. In my case, this problem was for a single project and didn't need to do this again.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same too, somebody advise me remove debug config, I have done it, but nothing happen, I make sure that the problem come from eclipse, just remove and install again,

Comment: And for you, if you installed it again worked out of the box?