# Eclipse can't find source when debugging java code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am new to Java and started with Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1. I started a small project that contains two classes, each in its own file:

- MIDI_Wrap_Test - a main (program) class
- MIDI_Wrap - another class (`MIDI_Wrap`) which is intended as a MIDI wrapper.   -

Both classes are in the same directory with file names being the same as the class name (with .java added of course). Something goes wrong and I want to debug it. However, when control transfers from the main program to the MIDI_Wrap file/class I get the error message 'source not found'.

I found out that this is a quite common error. The question and answer that seem to mirror my problem perfectly is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754207/i-get-source-not-found-when-debugging-my-java-code-in-eclipse). I added the project to the debug source path, noticing that the correct directories were already added but to no avail.

I must be doing something wrong but am not able to find out what. Can someone help me out of this?

Comment: This happens to me from time to time, especially on Maven projects, where the dependencies come from some repo some place. Usually when I get the 'can not find source' message, its accompanied by a button for you to browse to the source (I believe its the button in your link). Clicking that and manually navigating to my source directory, and the class im looking to debug usually works just fine. Have you tried this?

Comment: @Mark, yes, I tried that and that does not work. The source path is already present. Even in two ways: as a link to the project and as a link to the (correct) directory. And I do not use Maven or anything else special (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

I solved by shutting down eclipse and reopened it. This solved me, and code can be debug with source code view.